# Where can I find the source code of Android class SQLiteOpenHelper?

Tags: android

I want to take a look at the Android `SQLiteOpenHelper` class implementation, can somebody points me the location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link you want is:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java

But even better let me share a great tip:

This extension for Google Chrome
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/android-sdk-search/hgcbffeicehlpmgmnhnkjbjoldkfhoin?hl=en-GB adds the `ad` (as in Android Developer) keyword to your searchbar so you can type `ad TextView` and it will bring you directly to TextView on this example AND will add a link "View Source" next to the class name inside the site `https://developer.android.com/reference` so for any class you want to see the source it's just a click away.

Answer (score 2):

You can find all the existing versions here: http://grepcode.com/search?query=SQLiteOpenHelper&n=